# Why am I being downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Some users have intentionally downvoted me without any rational reason of that. For example I have achieved 16 down votes for some of my questions which are clear or useful! I would be so grateful of Meta Users, please check my profile and see what happened to my score! Maybe my question is not on topic for this page, but I do not know any other place that is suitable for presenting my problem.

(In at least one hour my recent questions had gotten down vote)

Comment: Please take a look at how I edited this question, maybe this can help you make your writing style more appropriate for this site.

Comment: You also might take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) .

Comment: Thank you so much for your editing. It have been professionally edited.

Answer (score 5):

You have come to the right place with your question. Unfortunately I think that there may be some reasons why you got downvoted. I only looked at your last question. Your pseudo code there seems to be a bit peculiar and it is hard to understand what you want. Your writing style is also somewhat different from most. This may lead our users to think of the question as "of low quality".

If this is also a question that is very strongly related to other questions you have asked, users may also react negatively towards this. The reasoning is then that you draw a lot of attention to "poor" questions and in addition you create work for other people, in the form of that questions like this will usually be edited and/or closed by users with more reputation.

I think you clearly showed effort in writing your pseudo code so I would like to help you. However, please consider the possiblity that your questions are not perfect and try be open to suggestions on improving them.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your following, I completely know what you say. I am sure that my last question seems to be unclear and boring, although it was a little peace of a larger program.  However my knowledge about mathematica syntax or function or ..... is very very low but its flexibility and kindness caused me to use of that.            Besides, it is a major question: regards to my last question which is not good, why other questions (that maybe previously  achieved up votes had to be down voted

Comment: @mr.0093, you are welcome! Also thank you very much for keeping an open mind to suggestions, you seem to be a good sport :). I hope all your questions will be answered in time :).